# asymptotic expansion of $\int_0^x e^{t^2} dt$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

I would like to find an asymptotic expansion of :

$$\int_0^x e^{t^2} \mathrm{d}t \text{ as } x \to \infty$$

I am enable to even find the first term.
I tried to find a function $g$ such that : $g \sim e^{t^2}$ and such that $g$ is an easy integrable function yet $2te^{t^2}$ doesn't work so I am kind of lost.

Comment: Have you looked up asymptotic expansions of $\operatorname{Erf}$? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Asymptotic_expansion

Comment: Taylor expansion of the integrand may be handy here